# IE Conditional statement not parsing correctly in DNN (dotnetnuke)

Tags: css, dotnetnuke-5, conditional-statements

I am using three conditional CSS files in my site, one for ie7, one for ie8 and one for IE only. IE7 and 8 are parsing properly when I parse the skin but for some reason, IE only conditional does not want to parse correctly, leaving this when the browser renders

```
<!--[if]> <![endif]-->
```

If however, I add that conditional statement directly to the parsed ascx page, the conditional works properly.

Here are the three conditional statements:

```
<!--[if IE]>
 <link href="/portals/0/skins/sunmedia2011/css/97iefixes.css" rel="stylesheet"   
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
 <link href="/portals/0/skins/sunmedia2011/css/98ie7fixes.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="/portals/0/skins/sunmedia2011/css/99ie8fixes.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `<!--[if gte IE 5]>` work? Cos if it does you could just use that - I'm sure no-one uses anything older than IE5 any more...

Comment: That worked...thanks Dave...not sure why IE only didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but could be helpful to someone:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="<%= SkinPath %>css/97iefixes.css" rel="stylesheet"   
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link href="<%= SkinPath %>css/98ie7fixes.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
<link href="<%= SkinPath %>css/99ie8fixes.css" rel="stylesheet" 
type="text/css">    
<![endif]-->
```